How to get download stats for artifacts in maven central?
We publish our projects to maven central using https://central.sonatype.com/. However, I didn't find there any download statistics. Could anyone say how to get this statistics if it possible.

You can view the statistics at https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/. Statistics for the current month are not available. They will only be generated in the following month. This always takes a few days.

@Bademeister Thank you for your help. Could you show how to do it. For example, we have in maven central - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-http . However, when I try to search by jetty-http, I don't see org.eclipse.jetty in results.

Are you the owner of the artifact? How do you publish this artifact? There are two ways. Can you log in to s01.oss.sonatype.org?

@Bademeister No, I am not the owner. I publish artifacts via central.sonatype.com as I said in my question. I can't log in to s01.oss.sonatype.org.

There are two ways to publish: Central Portal or OSSRH. As far as I know, the two areas have different user bases. That's why you can't register on s01.oss.sonatype.org. I registered on issues.sonatype.org (OSSRH) at the time, verified my GroupId and now have access to s01.oss.sonatype.org. Please see the answer below. Please ask the Sonatype support where you can view the statistics: support@sonatype.com

If you have an answer, can you please share it here?

@Bademeister Thank you for your help. I've already sent a message to central-support@sonatype.com , so, when/if they answer I will post the answer here.

@Bademeister I posted the answer from support.

I got the answer from support:

For the moment, download statistics is not possible for Central
Portal, we are working on that feature.

